# Adding more paramaters to a function with RenderRow (Onsen-UI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onsen-ui

So I have a list that currently calls a function to generate the ListItems, but I want to pass more info to it.

```
<List
  dataSource={this.state.addedArry}
  renderRow={this.renderList}
/>
```

Calls

```
  renderList = (user, index) => {
    return (
      <ListItem key={user.key}>
        <div className='left'>
          <img src={`https://robohash.org/${user.key}`} alt={""} className='list-item__thumbnail' />
        </div>
        <div className='center'>
          {user.name}
        </div>
        <div className='right'>
          <Button onClick={() => this.clickedRemoveEventHandler(user, index, this.state.userArry, this.state.addedArry)}>Remove</Button>
        </div>
      </ListItem>
    );
  }
```

I'm hoping there is a way to pass different data to it like this.state.userArry or something.

So the final call will look something like:

```
renderList = (user, index, inputArry, outoutArry) => { ... }
```

I've tried things like `renderRow={this.renderList(var1, var2)}` but they didn't work and I assume that has to do with the underlying map function

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would just access the extra info through props or state (i.e. `this.props.inputArray`). However, if you really want to pass more parameters, there are several ways:

- Binding the function beforehand to provide default params: `renderList = renderList.bind(this, inputArray, outputArray);`. Then, renderList will get 4 params: `renderList(inputArray, outputArray, data, index) { ... }`
- Binding the function "in place": `renderRow={renderList.bind(this, inputArray, outputArray)}`. Same arguments as the case before.
- Redirecting the arguments with an anonymous function: `renderRow={(data, index) => renderList(data, index, inputArray, outputArray)}`

Answer (score 0):

```
renderRow={(event) => {this.renderList(event, user, index, inputArry, outoutArry)}}
```

Do it like this , it will allow you to send n number of arguments to renderRow

Comment: Will it still automatically pass the `index` and `user` arguments?

Comment: I did `renderRow={() => {this.renderList("var1")}}` but now it wont let me add or remove items. I think that argument replaced the index one that is passed down by default

Comment: You need to pass all the explicit arguments separetly. you only get the event as the first target. Check my edited answer